# Hugo: siteparams equivalent to ref / relref?

Tags: hyperlink, hugo, hugo-shortcode

Part of Hugo's feature-set is a [really useful ability to provide links to pages in markdown through the the use of shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/content-management/cross-references/#use-of-ref-and-relref).

Unfortunately, shortcodes only work on markdown files (not on html files, partials, etc.).

Is there a way to do something similar in html files?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what problem you are trying to solve. But working with pages and relative vs absolute links and how to resolve is covered here:

https://gohugo.io/functions/getpage/#getpage-example

Also conversion to relative URLs and vice versa:

https://gohugo.io/functions/getpage/#getpage-example
https://gohugo.io/functions/absurl/